# Is "let" a modal?

Tags: verbs, past-tense, modal-verbs, reported-speech

Must the verb that follow *let* always be an infinitive regardless of the context, even in a reported speech?  For example,

> He told us to let him saw her one last time.

Is that correct?

Comment: No, it's not correct. _Let_ followed by a noun phrase takes an infinitive. Past tense verbs like _saw_ are **only** used in tensed clauses with nominative subjects (not _him_). There is an infinitive _saw_ meaning to use a saw on something (or in the case of the example sentence, someone). This is probably not what you want to say.

Comment: @JohnLawler it could be a retiring magician who's feeling nostalgic. ;)

Comment: If *let* were a modal, you couldn't make a *to*-infinitive out of it the way you just did. Modals are defective.

Comment: So, no, _let_ isn't a modal auxiliary verb. But you're not totally wrong; it **does** have modal senses. _Let_ occurs in many of the same kind of constructions that _shall_ does: _Let us/Let's dance_ means the same thing as _Shall we dance?_, and could be used in most of the same contexts with the same pragmatic intent. And the singular works the same way: _Let me open the window_ = _Shall I open the window?_ The modal auxiliary _shall_ is largely restricted to those constructions in American English, and clearly _let_ has some senses that govern deontic modality.

Comment: to let means to allow in your sentence.

Answer (score 2):

***TO LET*** is not a modal verb.
It is different from them semantically and formally.

1. "***Modality*** is about a speaker’s or a writer’s attitude towards the world.

A speaker or writer can express certainty, possibility, willingness, obligation, necessity and ability by using modal words and expressions.

Speakers often have different opinions about the same thing.

***Modal verbs***

Here are the main verbs we use to express modal meanings:

Core modal verbs: 
can, could, may, might, will, shall, would, should, must.

Semi-modals: 
dare, need, ought to, used to.

Other verbs with modal meanings: 
have (got) to, be going to and be able to."
(https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/modals-and-modality/modality-introduction)

***TO LET*** is an action verb.
It means 'to allow'.
It is also used as a polite way of making or responding to a suggestion, giving an instruction, or introducing a remark.

2. The forms of ***TO LET*** are also different from modals.
   It has the Infinitive, the Finite forms, can be in the Imperative Mood, is often used with modals.
   For example 
   (https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/):

// Could you let the dog out?

// Let's have a drink!

// They've let out their house.

// A tiny window that let in hardly any light.

Answer (score 2):

"Let's have a drink" is definitely of the hortative mood.

to say "let's do..." in Spanish you use the imperative mood, which as in many languages also covers hortative modality. NB. I'm a native english speaker

"Let me do this" is imperative but that's just the imperative form of let. This isn't "let" as a kind of modal verb itself.

Other uses of "let" are simply synonymous with "allow" or "permit" and work the same as them in indicative constructions.

I think let also used to be a modal subjunctive verb in older English, ie. "Let God bless you". "let them eat cake" might also be a jussive (but im not sure on that last bit)